# Populate and print array with random numbers using C

Tags: c, arrays, random

I'm trying to write a program that will populate an array of 100 elements with numbers between 1 and 22, and then print the array in a 20 x 5 table. I was able to populate the array and print it, but can only get it to work with numbers 1-100, how can I change it to only do numbers 1-22?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARY_SIZE 100

void random (int randNos[]);
void printArray (int data[], int size, int lineSize);

int main(void)
{
    int randNos [ARY_SIZE];

    random(randNos);
    printArray(randNos, ARY_SIZE, 20);

    return 0;
} 

void random (int randNos[])
{

   int oneRandNo;
   int haveRand[ARY_SIZE] = {0};

   for (int i = 0; i < ARY_SIZE; i++)
   {
      do
      {
        oneRandNo = rand() % ARY_SIZE;
      } while (haveRand[oneRandNo] == 1);
      haveRand[oneRandNo] = 1;
      randNos[i] = oneRandNo;
   }
   return;
}

void printArray (int data[], int size, int lineSize)
{

    int numPrinted = 0;

    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        numPrinted++;
        printf("%2d ", data[i]);
        if (numPrinted >= lineSize)
        {
         printf("\n");
         numPrinted = 0;
        }
   }
   printf("\n");
   return;
```

}

Comment: `rand() % ARY_SIZE` –> `rand() % 22 + 1`

Comment: You're using the `haveRand[]` array to avoid numbers that have already been used, but if you need to fill 100 array elements with random numbers from 1 to 22, then this is going to be impossible. Your `do ... while` loop will run forever.

Comment: i would suggest populating an array with the sequential values 1-22 and then [shuffling the array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).  it will be much faster.

Comment: @MFisherKDX you can fill an array of 100 elements with random numbers [1, 22] without having duplicates?

Comment: @Swordfish ... no.  i guess i am confused on the problem statement.  the OP should clarify what she is asking ... this could be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

@Sarah Simply include `time.h` header file (from the standard library), then rewrite your **random** function as follow:

```
void Random(int RandNos[])
{
   /*
    Since your random numbers are between 1 and 22, they correspond to the remainder of
    unsigned integers divided by 22 (which lie between 0 and 21) plus 1, to have the
    desired range of numbers.
   */
   int oneRandNo;
   // Here, we seed the random generator in order to make the random number truly "random".
   srand((unsigned)time(NULL)); 
   for(int i=0; i < ARY_SIZE; i++)
   {
       oneRandNo = ((unsigned )random() % 22 + 1);
       randNos[i] = oneRandNo; // We record the generate random number
   }
}
```

Note: You are asked to include `time.h` in order to use the `time()` function. If you are
working under Linux Or Mac OSX, you can find more information about this function by
type the command `man 3 time` in the terminal to easily access the documentation.

Also, naming your function `random` will conflict with that of the standard library. That is why I use `Random` instead.